# Setting a persistant android option menu

Tags: android, menu

I am looking for a way to have the options menu persist on screen as soon as the activity is opened without pressing the menu button of the simulator and it should be there until one of the options in the menu is pressed

Currently I have made an option menu like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
<item android:id="@+id/text"
    android:title="Text" />
<item android:id="@+id/icontext"
    android:title="Icon and text"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
</menu>
```

And my code is:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.icon:     
                            break;
        case R.id.text: 
                            break;
        case R.id.icontext: 
                            break;
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Please suggest changes in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity‘s option menu can be programatically opened and closed with the openOptionsMenu and closeOptionsMenu respectively

```
@Override 
public void onAttachedToWindow() { 
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  
    openOptionsMenu(); 
}
```

and to close:

```
closeOptionsMenu();
```

for lvls that do not support onAttachedToWindow could be used delayed execution(Not the best way):

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: I seems to have some problem using  onAttachedToWindow()  in android 1.6

Comment: on 1.6 you could just use this code without super.onAttachedToWindow();  line, then it will never be called

Comment: I have edited, you may use the second choose, but it is not very good design

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this one, but you could look at [openOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29).
Then after it's open you should try to intercept the menu button press and the back button press (as you would close the menu otherwise) and only disable this once one of the option items has been selected.

With this said, this all looks like a hack, so maybe you should consider a different solution for what you want to achieve.